# how to use variables read from file "a" into the main file "c", in a imported file "b"?

Tags: python, import

I have a file, say "c.py" and a imported file "b.py" which has its use in "c.py" later in the code

```
import b.py
def scatter_plot(file0,camp):

    # enter complete path of file
    file1 = ("/home/data/camp0" + str(camp) + "/not_detrended/ktwo"+ str(file0)+ "c0"+ str(camp)+ "_lpd_LC.txt")
    file2 = file1.replace("not_","")
    file3 = open('/home/parameters1.txt','r')

    y = np.genfromtxt(file1)
    x = np.genfromtxt(file2)
    text = file3.read()
    specs = text.split()

    #Input the parameters
    i = specs.index(str(file0))
    t0 = float(specs[i + 2])
    period = float(specs[i + 1])
    .......
```

In the main file c.py, I read the text file "file3" and get above variables(t0 and period). I have imported a file "b.py" which also uses these variables, but in order to get the code work I have to define and fix these variables in the file b.py before running c.py, I cant use them from "file3. I want to run the main file "c.py" by calling the function scatter_plot() and want that the variables also get defined in the imported file "b.py" from this. Simply when I call the function I want to use these variables in the imported file too. Is this possible ?

```
par = [tduration, depth, t0, period]    
firstmodel = traptransitover.traptransitover( time, par)
newmodel  = traptransitover.traptransitover( time, result)
```

the above code is few lines of "b.py". If I dont define the variables t0 and period in "b.py" and fix them before running "c.py" it dosen't work. But if I do so then there is no use of reading variables from "file3". I cannot define everytime before running the code.
 Sorry If I am unable to explain my problem and you need more clarity please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right

1. You need to share some variables between 3 modules.
2. To initialize this variables you need to read file
3. File is undefined at program start (i.e. you need parse argumets or read user input)

Best way is rewrite modules a.py, b.py and c.py, so thay will able to import without knowing this variables. All code that uses variables must be wrapped into functions or classes that accept (t0 and period) as parameters, and they should not be called until "c.py" not parse file.

Another way is create another module (for example "config.py") to store variables, and include this modules in all other modules, You will be unable to import other modules intill you initialize config with file.

`config.py`

```
t0 = None
period = None
def initialize_t_and_period( file ):
     global t0
     global period

     #here code for initialization t0 and period  from scatter_plot
```

module `b.py`

```
import config
do_something_with( config.t0 )
...
```

modules `c.py`

```
import config

def scatter_plot( file0, camp ):
    config.initialize_t_and_period( file0 )

    #after initialization you can safety import modules       
    import a
    import b
```

If file is always same (i.e. predefined), you can read it inside config.py. Despite the fact that config imported twice during program run it will executes only once.